# Stuck at passing values from selectcheckboxmenu to managedbean

Tags: jpa, jsf, primefaces, eclipselink

So I'm trying to create a "cookbook", and I'm stuck at passing a collection of objects to the managedbean, which would store it in a list.
Here is the part of the xhtml, where I'm adding the food:

```
<h:form>
                <h3>Insert food</h3>
                <label>Food ID</label>
                <h:inputText value="#{foodManagedBean.foodid}" ></h:inputText>
                <label>User ID</label>
                <h:inputText value="#{foodManagedBean.userid}" ></h:inputText>
                <label>Food name</label>
                <h:inputText value="#{foodManagedBean.foodname}" ></h:inputText>
                <label>Description</label>
                <h:inputText value="#{foodManagedBean.description}" ></h:inputText>
                <label>Cooking time in minutes</label>
                <h:inputText value="#{foodManagedBean.cooktime}" ></h:inputText>
                <label>Picture link</label>
                <h:inputText value="#{foodManagedBean.photo}" ></h:inputText>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                <h:outputLabel for="ingredients" value="Ingredients:"/>
                <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="ingredients" value="#{foodManagedBean.ingredientList}"
                                      label="Ingredients" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:250px">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{ingredientManagedBean.allIngredients}"/>
                </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <br/><br/>

                <h:commandButton value="Insert" action="#{foodManagedBean.insertFood()}"></h:commandButton>
                <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{foodManagedBean.deleteFood()}"></h:commandButton>
```

I'm trying to store the selected items in the "foodManagedBean.ingredientList", and the available ingredients are in the "ingredientManagedBean.allIngredients" list. Ingredients have 3 attributes, an id, a name and a price.

And here is the part of the managedbean where I'm trying to persist the object through a facade:

```
 public void insertFood() {
        Food f = new Food();
        f.setCookTime(getCooktime());
        f.setDescription(getDescription());
        f.setFoodName(getFoodname());
        f.setPhoto(getPhoto());
        f.setFoodPK(new FoodPK(getFoodid(), getUserid()));
        f.setUser1(new User1(getUserid()));
        f.setIngredientCollection(ingredientList);
        foodFacade.create(f);
    }
```

If I try something like sout(ingredientList), I'm getting the names of the ingredients which are selected, but whenever I try to make this insertion happen, I'm getting a "Transaction aborted" error, which's stacktrace is the following:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:729)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy280.create(Unknown Source)
    at hu.bmrk.cookbook.managedbeans.FoodManagedBean.insertFood(FoodManagedBean.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:490)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:854)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:723)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.checkForUnregisteredExistingObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4192)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(CollectionMapping.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.cascadeDiscoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(ObjectBuilder.java:2515)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.discoverAndPersistUnregisteredNewObjects(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.discoverUnregisteredNewObjects(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.calculateChanges(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:723)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3168)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:452)
    ... 59 more
```

I'm guessing that my mistake is that the list I'm giving to the managedbeans is null, but I just don't understand why, since if I print that out, I'm getting the content of the list.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think your problem may not be PrimeFaces or JSF but its that you are trying to do a JPA Cascade of the Ingredient List to be inserted updated.  And it looks like EclipseLink is blowing up trying to persist the collection.   I would create a simpler example and just try and insert a hard coded Food object with hard coded Ingredient List and call your Facade.  Take PF/JSF out of the equation and see if you get it to work.

Comment: @Melloware thanks, will give it a shot as soon as I’ll have time :)

Comment: If the list ends up on the server, jsf and PrimeFaces have done their job.

Comment: Check all here: https://www.google.com/search?q=jpa+UnitOfWorkImpl.checkForUnregisteredExistingObject%28UnitOfWorkImpl.java

Comment: Totally EclipseLink related...